# How to access an Alembic velocity attribute?

Tags: motion-blur, alembic

I'm trying to get motionblur to work on an imported Alembic mesh.
I can see that the Color-Attribute ("Cd") shows up correctly inside Blender as vertex colors, but what about my velocity attribute which works fine when I test it with Vray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet supported, see https://developer.blender.org/D2388